# Can't get my PHP document to connect to my xampp server

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to php, and am sorry if this question turns out to be too vague, but if there is any other information that you need from me let me know.

Anyway, basically what my problem is I have some simple php code that should call die() if it can't connect to the xampp server I have set up, however, even if I put in invalid info for the server or user it prints Successful.  I really don't know where to go with this, so if anyone has any suggestions that would be great.

```
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';



if ( !mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) )
{
    die(mysql_error());
} 
else
    echo 'Succesful';

?>
```

Ok for some reason it was just not working with the root user, so I created a new user who required a password and apparently that connected like it was supposed to.  Thanks everyone for the answers.

Comment: Just said, you need to do it because, based on this, people will hesitate to answer you. PS: That includes me! :)

Comment: lol accepted a wrong answer, thats a hell of a huge encouragement lol lol!

Comment: lol just saw your edit, Tell me what was your original question. You are not being able to connect to the mysql with `root` username or You get success message even you didnot specified mysql password? I m confused now

Comment: by the way for xampp server, `localhost` and `root` username without password is a default settings which works. That was not the invalid info for the server

Comment: sorry for the confusion but basically the mysql_connect() function I had above was never returning false, even when i had invalid values in $dbhost or $dbuser.  What I did was in phpmyadmin i created a new user which required a password and it started working, returning false if I had an invalid user etc.  Sorry if my question is still confusing

Comment: also i chose his comment because he gave me the idea to create a new user other then root and try it.  It might not have been the exact purpose of their comment but it ended up working for me in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that when trying to connect php to an xampp server there are usually only a few things that could cause the issue you are having.

```
1. mySQL service is not running
2. no specific database is selected to try to access
3. user does not exist in phpmyadmin.
```

When you pick a user to connect php to mySQL with you should always make sure that a password is set, that is usually the thing people miss. You can use root if you create another instance of it in the user list and require a password, or you can add a password to the root user already in the list, but the best option is to create a new custom user that only has access to the database you want to access with your php and make sure it has a password required. (make sure any user you use can connect with localhost; root can by default and I think most newly created users can as well).

Below is the php I use for websites I design that need php to access a DB.

```
<?php
// This configures the variables for database access
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '????';
$dbpass = '????';
$dbname = '????';


// This will connect to the server and then the correct database
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db($dbname);
?>
```

Comment: well if his mysql is not running, user doesnot exist, he would have get error in first place,

Comment: not sure what the vote down was for. I simple defined all possible events where php and mySQL could not connect. I have had the exact same issue more than once and resolved the issue every time with the method I stated above. If the op can connect to the server using valid credentials, then most of my post would become invalid and the line $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql'); could be used to resolve the error of always printing Successful. (it would print Error connecting to mysql if connection failed)

Comment: Well, his question was not that he couldnot connect to mysql. His question was why the code connects to mysql despite not selecting the database. You gave the irrelevant answer to his question, this might be the reason someone downvoted.  Try to read his question again

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct pistolpete333. For your root user issue, that your not able to connect with root user you can check below file for your phpmyadmin configuration

```
C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.5.1\config.inc.php.
```

In above file you can check your host, username and password of phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

This is working because you have specified valid username, host and password to mysql. If you specify wrong password, you get mysql error. This code works and connects to the mysql server though you have not selected any database.

Try this code instead

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// make foo the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('foo', $link); //foo is your database name
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```